# How would I say "I will get laughed at"?

Tags: word-choice

Was wondering what it would be . My best guess was the following but couldn't figure out the term

我會(____) 笑？

Comment: w/o 被：lexical passive：我会受到大家（人们）的嘲笑
cf。CCG Ch.13 The passive voice and 被 constructions 13,1
Three forms of passive (a) notional passive 问题解决了 （b）formal passive 问题终被解决 （c）lexical passive 问题得到了解决， 问题得到解决了

Comment: @j dough, you are almost there. You need only a 被. For example, "If I go out like this, I will get laughed at." 如果我這樣出去，我會被笑。

Comment: ＂叫＂、＂让＂、＂给＂ instead of 被：我会让（叫，给）人（大家、人们）嘲笑的。我会给嘲笑的。
cf.＂实用现代汉语语法＂：在口语里，表示被动意义时＂让＂、＂叫＂比＂被＂用得更普遍。＂让＂、＂叫＂也多用于对主语来说是不愉快或受损害的事情。包含有＂让＂、＂叫＂的句子在结构上与包含＂被＂的句子基本一样，只是介词＂让＂、＂叫＂的宾语一定要出现。在口语里，介词＂给＂也可以表示被动的意思，南方人用得较多。介词＂给＂后可以有宾语可以没有宾语,
also note combined use of 被 、让、叫 （introducing agent）with 给 before verb：我会被（让、叫）人给嘲笑的

Comment: It seems the notional passive also is possible: 我会嘲笑的，note that 嘲笑 is transitive，whereas mere 笑 can be used both intransitively (laugh) and transitively (laugh at), because of its intransitive meaning 我会笑的 apparently can only mean "I will laugh"。The question arises whether present day frequent use of 被-passive is due to western influence. 问题出现了：目前经常由＂被＂组成的被动语态是否在西方影响下出现的。

Answer (score 4):

"我會**被**人**笑**" - "I will **get laughed at** "

"我會**被**人**笑話**" - "I will be **joked at**"

“我會**被**人**取笑**” - "I will be **made fun of**"

“我會**被**人**耻笑**” - "I will be **ridiculed**"

**Edit:**

Add '嘲笑' (to ridicule)(*as TXV  suggested*) and 譏笑 ( to sneer at; to mock; to ridicule)

“我會**被**人**嘲笑**” - "I will be **ridiculed**"

“我會**被**人**譏笑**” - "I will be **ridiculed**"

Comment: 會被人笑我 doesn't sound as good as 我會被人笑

Comment: I don't think it matters, but I would change it anyway. Now all the example sentences are in the same grammar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Following your sentence structure, I would say:

> 我會被别人嘲笑

Notably, I'm using 别人 (other people) and the two-character verb 嘲笑。

However Chinese language is not as generous with passive forms as other languages. In this case it still sounds okay, but you may want to consider an active form as:

> 别人會嘲笑我

which I prefer.

Answer (score -1):

大方笑也。

“Body must be at least 30 characters： you entered 5.”

Comment: “Body must be at least 30 characters： you entered 5.” => please enter some meaningful characters.

Answer (score -2):

I will get laughed at " 我会被人嘲笑

Comment: The exact sentence is in my answer already,